# Communication between and Arduino controller and a Qt Application

Tags: qt, operating-system, serial-port, arduino

My brother has asked for help on this great side project he has been working on, but the tools he is using are new to me and I am not sure where to start reading.

The problem is this: We have an application built using Qt running on a Linux machine. We've connected an Arduino-controller via USB (this is read as a virtual com port). The idea is to have a graphical interface for controlling the lights in his house. The Arduino reports every five seconds whether or not the light to which it is connected is turned on. You can send a command to the Arduino to turn the light on/off.

I have experience dong higher level software projects, but I have never written anything to interface with external hardware in this way. I have limited knowledge of OS capabilities.

I need to learn to do the following:

1. How do I get the incoming signal from the Arduino about the light being on/off to our Qt application?
2. How do I get a signal out from the Qt application to the Arduino to tell it to turn the light on/off?

I should say that I have successfully setup one-way communication with the Arduino using minicom. I can see the pulse every five seconds indicating the light status. I am not yet able to send the "turn on/turn off" signal in the other direction.

I would appreciate enormously any advice on what to read to learn what I need to learn. I have had some success reading materials on the Arduino found via google (that's how I got minicom working), but I am having trouble finding the right information for integrating with Qt. My ignorance of the details of how operating systems work is hampering me.

Comment: You'll need to open the Arduino's serial port (probably /dev/ttyUSBXX, XX is random) and use the `<termios.h>` interface to communicate to the Arduino afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is some way of communicating with the serial port, ideally without handling all the operating-system dependent stuff. If using Qt4 in conjunction with Python, [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) is probably the way to go. For Qt/C++ there are some extensions that could be handy, like [qextserialport](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) for example.

Comment: Okay, yeah. I suspected that I was overcomplicating things.